# How to get current location correctly in Android? Using Location and LocationManager class

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I'm developing an application which get the current location from Network, however I'm getting an error in that line code: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);

```
public void getLocation(){
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    this.location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location != null){
        this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
        this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);

}
```

I'm calling the object of this class within doInBackground method of a AsyncTask.

Here is my logcat:

```
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450): Process: com.fb.newcomersapp, PID: 12450
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:844)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:857)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:454)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at com.fb.newcomersapp.LocationTracker.getLocation(LocationTracker.java:48)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at com.fb.newcomersapp.FeedActivity$LocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(FeedActivity.java:105)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at com.fb.newcomersapp.FeedActivity$LocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(FeedActivity.java:1)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 14:47:42.939: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Where's your logcat?

Comment: Are you able to compile or is the error in syntax? Does your AsyncTask implement the LocationListener interface?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Logcat added

Comment: @Tardo logcat added.

Comment: @zgc7009 Yes, I'm able to compile. GPSTracker class that is the class that contain this code, implements LocationListener.

Comment: Oh that actually makes sense. locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this); implicitly adds a handler, which you can't do inside of an AsyncTasks doInBackground (that I am aware of). You need to make that request call from the main thread.

Comment: It worked for me, thx thx! I did not know about this. But location.getlatitude/longitude returns 0.  thx!